# Drop-down list not loading after validation on page reload

Tags: javascript, stripes

I have a form and a dropdown as below:

[image]

I have written validation alerts for other fields which are above this drop-down. But when any of the validation triggers, this drop-down is not being repopulated after page reload and is being displayed as below:

[image]

I have the below in my jsp:

```
<tr><td>
<stripes:checkbox name="policyShow" onclick="handleDisable(policyShow, policyNumber,null)"/><stripes:label for="DealerTransactionReport.policy" /></td>
<td>                
<stripes:select name="policyNumber" disabled="${!actionBean.policyShow}" onchange="handleSelectedAll();">
<stripes:options-collection collection="${actionBean.policyList}" value="policyNumber" label="description" />
</stripes:select>

</td>
</tr>
```

I tried writing an onchange function but nothing worked so far and I currently have below code:

```
 function handleSelectedAll()
{
       var select = document.forms['dealerTransactionForm'].policyNumber.options[document.forms['dealerTransactionForm'].policyNumber.selectedIndex].index;
if(select== 0 )
{
document.forms[dealerTransactionForm].searchTxt.value="";        
}

}
```

Can someone please suggest how do I solve this problem??.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are loosing data during the postback. You need to fetch data during the page load regardless of the selected value of the dropdown-list.  Please be noted that only the selected value is passed to the server and not all select options.